# Is there a Node OAuth Server Implementation

Tags: node.js, oauth

I only found the oauth client library for nodejs. Does anybody know where I can find a server implementation?

Thanks,

Hao.

Comment: See my impl `"oauth2-server": "^3.0.0-b2"` https://github.com/manjeshpv/node-oauth2-server-implementation

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I've just released [OAuthorize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauthorize), which is a suite of middleware for implementing an OAuth 1.0a server.  It is highly modular, letting you tune it to meet your requirements.  It integrates seamlessly with [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) for authentication, using [passport-http-oauth](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-oauth) to protect APIs using access tokens.

**Update:** [OAuth2orize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize) is now available.  It follows similar patterns, but implements support for OAuth 2.0.

Comment: Thumbs up! Very neat and versatile implementation.

Comment: This project has gone stale in 2012.  As of July 2013, this project is still current https://github.com/nightworld/node-oauth2-server

Comment: Why do you say its gone stale?  It fully implements the spec and there are no critical bugs.  It doesn't get regular commits, because it doesn't need them.  It's mature, deployed many places.  Not stale.

Comment: @JaredHanson you really are so much awesome !!! I owe you a few work days :-)

Comment: Just my .02 here but have chatted with @JaredHanson a couple times. Quality dev, used OAuth2orize and ver 1.0 on sever production apps. rock solid. Not sure where the "stale" talk is coming from but that's ridiculous. sorry had to comment.

Answer (score 10):

Pierre Ruyssen has a few OAuth2 projects. I've never used them nor do I know how far along they are, but you could check them out:

- https://github.com/AF83/oauth2_server_node
- https://github.com/AF83/oauth2_client_node
- https://github.com/AF83/auth_server

Comment: Thank you Tauren, But I just need to support OAuth 1.0A server right now. I think I might use these module later :D

Comment: Just to save you all some time, all of these projects have their latest commits as being sometime in 2010 or 2011.

Answer (score 8):

Searching http://search.npmjs.org I found https://github.com/selead/oauth-server, but it uses **OAuth 1.0A protocol** and **last commit was at April 19, 2011**. But then again I guess you should just have look and it might just fit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

I found another one: https://github.com/ammmir/node-oauth2-provider. It use Connect and ExpressJS.