# 2-legged server side oauth implementation in node.js

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

I have a node.js API that I want to protect via 2-legged OAuth.  Was wondering if anyone knows of a server side implementation for this.  Please note that this is for server to server communication and is not to provide user authentication via a 3rd party server.

Comment: https://github.com/ammmir/node-oauth2-provider

Comment: There are a few around. See the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822840/is-there-a-node-oauth-server-implementation for details.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [passport-http-oauth](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-oauth), a [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) authentication strategy.  It implements the OAuth HTTP authorization scheme, and can be used independently of the user authorization flow (as is the case with 2-legged OAuth).