# how to provide oauth access to my web service

Tags: node.js, oauth

Searching online for oauth yields various platforms and how to sign in, etc but has no resources on how to provide oauth access myself.

How would I go about building a platform allowing 3rd party access? Are there any tutorials?

Eventually I want to make a [`passport`](http://passportjs.org/) plugin if that helps in suggestions.

Comment: I could be wrong, but are you looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822840/is-there-a-node-oauth-server-implementation?

Comment: yea pretty much! couldn't find it googling for my life

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use these:

[OAuthorize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauthorize), which is a suite of middleware for implementing an OAuth 1.0a server.

[OAuth2orize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize) for OAuth 2.0.