# How to obtain a Token in an Autonomous Client (Username-Password Flow)

Tags: node.js, twitter-oauth

I am trying to use the `grant_type=password` oauth flow with [Twitter API](https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token). How can I implement this flow in `nodejs`.

```
var twitterConsumerKey = '';
var twitterConsumerSecret = '';

var OAuth2 = require('oauth').OAuth2;
var oauth2 = new OAuth2(
    twitterConsumerKey,
    twitterConsumerSecret,
    'https://api.twitter.com/',
    null,
    'oauth2/token',
    null
);
oauth2.getOAuthAccessToken(
    '',
    {'grant_type':'client_credentials'},
    function (e, access_token, refresh_token, results){
        console.log('bearer: ',access_token);
    }
);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822840/is-there-a-node-oauth-server-implementation

Comment: @user503413 I have updated the question where Im using node-auth module. Is {'grant_type':'password'} possible in the same module?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like twitter support [Application Only Authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth).

I'm not familiar with the oauth module but you can use [`mikeal/request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request) as follows:

```
var request = require('request');

request.post({
  url: 'https://api.twitter.com/',
  auth: {
    user: twitterConsumerKey,
    pass: twitterConsumerSecret
  },
  form: { grant_type:'client_credentials'},
  json: true
}, function (err, resp, body) {

  var token = body.access_token;

  //now you can use it for other APIs
  request.get({
    url: '....',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  }, function () {});

});
```

Comment: your example shows { grant_type:'client_credentials'}. Im looking for { grant_type:'password'}.I want to implement oauth client

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. Then you are looking for the oauth __resource owner__ flow, and I think twitter doesn't support it.

Comment: Yes I need resource owner flow using npm.